# How to get first 10 character of a text minus some characters from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

Say I got a text stored in a MYSQL table.  I want to get the first 10 characters of a text minus some characters. for example if I got a text with string "1AB2345AB67890EBF".  I want to retrieve the first 10 character from that string excluding the unique string "AB" that it finds.  So in this example the first 10 characters of the string "1AB2345AB67890EBF" minus the string "AB" would be "1234567890".  I know the MYSQL query "SELECT LEFT(column,10) FROM table" will select the first 10 characters but those 10 character will include the "AB".  How can I retrieve the first 10 character without including the "AB" in the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` for this:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(`column`,'AB',''),10) FROM `table`;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you first remove `AB`, and only then take 10 characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE("1AB2345AB67890EBF","A", ""), "B", ""), 10)
```

This should be what you looking for.

Edit

added [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/43656)

Comment: this solution will delete the A and B separately even they are split. Let me know if you only want to remove the pattern match 'AB' only

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(TableName.ColumnName, 'TheTextToFind', 'TheTextToReplacedBy'), 10), TableName.OtherColumns, ... FROM TableName;
```

Example:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(TableName.SomeColumnName, 'AB', ''), 10) FROM TableName;
```